# Avoid cloning HTMLTemplate to retrieve innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, underscore.js-templating, html5-template

I have all templates in `<template>` tags to improve runtime performance (avoids rendering), but I am wondering if I am using them correctly when I need their contents for compiling my Underscore templates. What *I want* is the string content of the DOM element, but I seem unable to access it without cloning it from the shadow DOM. I am doing this:

```
function compileTemplate(templateId){
    var el = document.getElementById(templateId);
    var templateMarkup = _.unescape(el.cloneNode(true).innerHTML);
    return compiledTemplate = _.template(templateMarkup);
}
```

This works, but is there a more efficient that avoids cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the `innerHTML` string directly without cloning:

```
function compileTemplate(templateId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(templateId);
    var templateMarkup = _.unescape(el.innerHTML);
    return compiledTemplate = _.template(templateMarkup);
}
```

```js
function compileTemplate(templateId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(templateId);
    console.log( el.innerHTML )
}

function test() {
    compileTemplate('T1')
}
```

```html
<template id=T1>
  HTML inside
</template>

<button onclick=test()>Compile</button>
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how that escaped me. Heh, pun actually unintended :-) I think I just used node.content and got nowhere.